# Yarn berry installs node_modules

Tags: node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v3

node.js version: 16.14.0
yarn version: 3.1.1
macOS: 11.6.4 (Big Sur)

I set up and continue to work on a yarn workspace project. I committed all files including `.yarn`, `.pnp.cjs`, `.pnp.loader.mjs` on the github repo.

However, I got an issue after I changed my computer.

When I tried to clone the repo and execute `yarn install` from my desktop computer, it deleted `.pnp.cjs` and `.pnp.loader.mjs` files and installed `node_modules`.

Other colleagues don't experience this issue, neither on my other laptop. Node and other versions are same.

I tried to delete and reinstall the repo several times, but the results went same, too.

I know that node_modules can be installed despite of using Yarn berry when the dependencies include binary. But I don't think this is the case.

Below is the shell message when `node_modules` is installed.

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 353ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-android-arm-eabi@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-android-arm64@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-darwin-arm64@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-freebsd-x64@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-arm-gnueabihf@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-arm64-gnu@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-arm64-musl@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-x64-gnu@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-x64-musl@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-win32-arm64-msvc@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-win32-ia32-msvc@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-win32-x64-msvc@npm:1.2.126 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-android-arm-eabi@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-android-arm64@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-darwin-arm64@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-freebsd-x64@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-arm-gnueabihf@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-arm64-gnu@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-arm64-musl@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-x64-gnu@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-linux-x64-musl@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-win32-arm64-msvc@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-win32-ia32-msvc@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0076: │ @swc/core-win32-x64-msvc@npm:1.2.133 The darwin-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 8s 368ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 9s 31ms
```

I got a different message when trying on my other computer which works well.

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 428ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: │ ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 0s 841ms
```

Answer (score 6):

You are having `.yarnrc.yml` file in one of the parent directories with `nodeLinker: node-modules` option inside it (maybe in your user home folder?), find this file and remove it.